# Interact through df columns and filter then with a like string statement

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine a dataset with multiple columns, that start with carr

| carr | carrer | banana |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |

How can i filter through these columns names, and return only those who start with the string "carr".

Wanted result

| carr | carrer |
| --- | --- |
| One | Two |

Sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({
    "Carrer":[1,2,3],
    "Carr":[2,3,1],
    "Banana":[1,5,7]
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.filter`

```py
out = df.filter(regex='(?i)^carr')
```

```
print(out)

   Carrer  Carr
0       1     2
1       2     3
2       3     1
```

Comment: Could you make it so the regex, is not case sensitive. So that the regex accepts uppercase and lowercase? Please

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 Edited with inline flagger.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a comprehension:

```
sub = [col for col in df.columns if col.lower().startswith('carr')]
df[sub]
```

Output:

| carr | carrer |
| --- | --- |
| One | Two |

Comment: You could use `df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('Carr')]`

Comment: @mozway. Much better than my update :) Maybe add `.str.lower()`

Comment: @Corralien TBH, I would myself use `filter` ;)